# JavaScript (Have one button open and close something)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a hamburger menu and when you click on the hamburger, it will turn into an x. I want it so that when you click on the hamburger, it will open the menu and if you click the x, it will close the menu.

This is my code so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px !important;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: .9s;
}

.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">

  <a href="#">...</a>
  <a href="#">...</a>
  <a href="#">...</a>
  <a href="#">...</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav(); closeNav()>
<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
</span>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: just use one event and a variable that saves if it's open or closed.

Comment: Are you even using jQuery? I see you tagged this question with jQuery, but I do not see a jQuery script included in your page.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a toggle function like this:

```
function toggleNav() {
    var sidenav = document.getElementById("mySidenav"),
    main = document.getElementById("main");
    sidenav.style.width = sidenav.style.width === "250px" ? '0' : '250px';
    main.style.marginLeft = main.style.marginLeft === "250px" ? '0' :  '250px';
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="toggleNav();">...</span>
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/df4cuet5/

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use.

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("open close");
});
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/c7zrmoad/

Comment: This is good jquery, but it doesn't look like OP is using jquery in his scripting

Comment: I don't think OP is using jquery but this is the easiest ways to do it.

Comment: I assumed the jQuery tag for the question was put there by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

A simple fix is to have two classes assigned to that button.
Say class="Original Open" i.e., one class = Original, another class=Open

Now in your Javascript file, you write an onclick function for Open class by first finding Original class.In that onclick function, you show the Menu Container, add another class say "Close" to that button when you click it the first time AND remove the class "Open".

Now write the onclick function for the class "Close" which hides your Menu and also removes that class "Close" and adds the class "Open" again.

Simple logic..!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(x) { document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.toggle("open");
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px !important;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: .9s;
}

.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}

/* ----- START -----  */

.open {
  width: 250px;
}
.open ~ #main {
  margin-left: 250px;
}

/* ----- END ----- */
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">...</a>
  <a href="#">...</a>
  <a href="#">...</a>
  <a href="#">...</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <span style="cursor:pointer">
    <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```