# Sidebar not responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I currently have 2 problems with my sidebar.

1. The upper part is cut off on mobile devices.
2. The sidebar is unfolded by default on mobile devices. It shouldn’t be like this. And when it is folded, the content of the page does not shift to the left. However, the content should shift to the left.

I use bootstrap 5.

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 45px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 5%), 0 2px 10px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
  width: 220px;
}

.sidebar .active {
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 16%), 0 2px 10px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .main {
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 220px;
    /* 180 + 40 */
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
          <div class="position-sticky pt-3">
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{{ path('app_dashboard') }}">
                  <span data-feather="home"></span> Test
                </a>
                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="{{ path('app_dashboard') }}">
                  <span data-feather="home"></span> Test
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">
                  <span data-feather="file"></span> Test
                </a>
                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">
                  <span data-feather="file"></span> Test
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  <span data-feather="file-plus"></span> Test
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  <span data-feather="users"></span> Test
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Media Queries to determine what action to do based on the screen size. Here, you would want to change the position/size of the sidebar based on the screen size.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) { 

*This is for phones, for example (you might need to find more accurate pixel counts)*

}
```

**Edit:**

I just saw that you already have Media Queries. Try changing the size and position too, though, not just the padding.

**Edit:**
Here's a quick demo. This should be more than enough to solve your issue. Here's another [link to help you](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp). I would appreciate if you marked this answer as correct. Thanks!

```js
function openNav() {
  const a = document.getElementById("sidebarMenu");
  const b = document.getElementsByClassName("CLASS NAME HERE");
  a.style.width = "220px";
  for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    b[i].style.width = "100%";
  }
}
function closeNav() {
  const a = document.getElementById("sidebarMenu");
  const b = document.getElementsByClassName("CLASS NAME HERE");
  a.style.width = "0";
  for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    b[i].style.width = "0";
  }
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 45px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 5%), 0 2px 10px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
    width: 220px;
}
 
.sidebar .active {
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 16%), 0 2px 10px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
}

.closebtn {
position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
 
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .sidebar {
        padding: 120px 0 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<span onclick="openNav()">open</span>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar collapse">
                    <div class="position-sticky pt-3">
                        <ul class="nav flex-column">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{{ path('app_dashboard') }}">
                                    <span data-feather="home"></span> Test
                                </a>
                                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="{{ path('app_dashboard') }}">
                                    <span data-feather="home"></span> Test
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">
                                    <span data-feather="file"></span> Test
                                </a>
                                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">
                                    <span data-feather="file"></span> Test
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                    <span data-feather="file-plus"></span> Test
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                    <span data-feather="users"></span> Test
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mhm that doen't have an effect. Could you give me a possible solution, please?
And what is with problem 2 please?

Comment: Did you change the size/position of .sidebar, not .main? If you haven't changed .sidebar, try that. If you did, let me know and I'll try to help.

Comment: Yes, I changed .sidebar in @media (max-width: 600px) {  but it doesn’t work

Comment: Which values should I use?

Comment: Use max-width: 600px on mobile devices and min-width: 600px on laptops. Have both of those cases. Then, delete the top part (the part that defines the sidebar outside of the media query). Experiment with different sizes for width (try really small and really big values, just to get an idea of what is happening). If it's still not working, put that updated code in your answer and I'll take another look at it.

Comment: It’s much better now. Thank you very much.
Unfortunately, I still have the problem that the text is partly behind the sidebar. How can I fix the problem?

Unfortunately, I also have the problem that the sidebar on mobile devices is automatically unfolded. That must not be the case. The sidebar should be folded automatically.
`@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .sidebar {
        padding: 120px 0 0;
    }
}`
[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/sVzEYm5)
I would like if you fold the sidebar, the text would also slide to the left.
And not like this.
[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/pwQDC26)

Comment: For your first problem, could you post the code that allows you to switch between folding and unfolding the sidebar? For your second question, inside the media query, you need to change the padding for the text. So, whenever the sidebar is folded, inside that media query, change the padding to be close to the left side of the screen (so only a little padding). When it's unfolded, adjust the padding so you can see it. (NOTE: I'm assuming that "folded" means it's to the side and you can't see the buttons, whereas "unfolded" means you can see all the options.)

Comment: Problem 1 is solved. Class collapse was missing.

But could you help me with problem 2 please?

My html: https://pastebin.com/SZVG2n22
my css: https://pastebin.com/9eZyyZqh

I use bootstrap 5.

Comment: I updated my answer- it should be more than enough to help you. Please mark it as correct if it does. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, that’s not quite what I’m looking for.

I want to be able to open AND close it with a Hamburger Menu.

Comment: Here's an answer to your question (the first answer seems like what you want): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38379429/javascript-have-one-button-open-and-close-something